# R memoise to filesystem with a non-identical match condition

Tags: r, memoization, memoise

I would like to use the `memoise` package with `cache_filesystem` to cache long running functions for use in a shiny application. This almost works perfectly, the problem is that the input is a list object that contains a (amongst other things) a db connection which will change. I want to ignore this element in my input object.

The db connection will change from session to session, but I need `memoise` to only look at the `id` element in the input, and not the other elements in the list. Is there a way I can do this? I have looked at the `...` argument but this seems to only further restrict, not relax.

Simplified example below:

```
localCache = cache_filesystem("memoiseCache/")
input1_1 = list(id = "id1", dbConn = 100)
input1_2 = list(id = "id1", dbConn = 101)

testFun=function(input) {
  print("Running the function")
  return(100)
}
library(memoise)
testFun.mem = memoise(testFun)

# This will run the function for the initial time - CORRECT
> testFun.mem(input1_1)
[1] "Running the function"
[1] 100

# This will now fetch the cached result - CORRECT
> testFun.mem(input1_1)
[1] 100

# I need this to ignore the dbConn element and instead fetch the cached result
> testFun.mem(input1_2)
[1] "Running the function"
[1] 100
```

EDIT: The input to my function actually points to a static DB so there are no issues with caching the results, *which* static DB is pointed to is defined by the `id` element, but different connections can be made to the same DB. The functions can be arbitrarily complicated. For example:

```
function(dbInputObj){
  <Many table joins and aggregations>
  <Some logic and conditions>
  <More table joins>
  return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper function to hide the differences. I cannot see how your app works from the simplified code though.

Are you connecting to same database with different `dbConn`? Are you trying to cache the database inquiry or some calculation after database inquiry?

I don't think it's a good idea to cache database inquiry if the `dbConn` can be different. You are supposed to get updated data from database, not caching it.

If you want to cache the calculation after database inquiry, just get the value first, then memoise the calculation function with the values only, not the database connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've edited the question with more information. As I want to allow the functions to be arbitrarily complex I can't think of a way to do this without just "hiding" some elements of the input list from `memoise` - which may not be possible?

Comment: I still think it's more logical to cache in database end, though you can use a simple hack (not really recommended in concept): get dbConn as a variable, write a function that take dbConn as global variable instead of parameter. This break multiple assumptions of `memoise` but may work for your case.